# Looking for an open source and better alternative for windows performance monitor

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance

Is there any open source and better alternative for windows performance monitor?

Thank you,

Comment: I am a bit confused why this question is closed. Windows performance monitor is basic and it is not the most user friendly tool. Paid alternatives such as Microsoft system center could cost high. I have been referred to **PolyMon** and **PolyMonRT** as reasonable alternative. I am trying them for a few hours and they are working nicely. I am just sharing here, so it might help someone with similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Dump the data to a CSV via PowerShell and WMI then make a nice graph.  What do you want that PerfMon isn't doing?

Comment: Well to start with it's impossible to even use that crap since all of the UI is non-resizable unusable rubbish. Also good luck modifying instance name for volatile counters - requires a re-add which itself requires going through that nightmare UI once again. And again and again. So yeah, like the OP I want a tool that is possible to use, dumping the data to a CSV is not the best way to explore counters and look at the data in real time. So I don't get the downvote and closure, this is a legitimate problem